# How to test for normal execution exit code?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

```
func! ShouldReformat()
  return normal :w !elm-format --stdin --validate
endfunc

func! Reformat()
  if ShouldReformat()
    normal gggqG
  endif
endfunc
```

But `return normal` is not taken into account, how can I test that ?

Comment: I can probably use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530456/how-do-i-send-the-current-buffer-or-line-as-stdin-to-system-in-vim

Answer (score 1):

```
func! ShouldReformat()
  write !elm-format --stdin --validate
  return v:shell_error
endfunc
```

`v:shell_error` returns the last shell execution exit code

```
:help shell_error
v:shell_error   Result of the last shell command.  When non-zero, the last
                shell command had an error.  When zero, there was no problem.
                This only works when the shell returns the error code to Vim.
                The value -1 is often used when the command could not be
                executed.  Read-only.
```

Comment: You dont need normal here; the bodies of functions are Ex commands. So just `write !elm-format …` is fine.

Comment: Then elm had an output, so I guess i'll swap for system()

Comment: Ok, my error was dumb : I used system(..., join(getline(1, '$'), "\n")), and was missing the closing "\n"